# Passing a variable from Child component to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, components, react-props

I am not getting the `index` from the `event => { this.handleChange(event, index) }` from the Child component, and I suspect the `event` isn't arriving either. I don't know how to transfer it up to the parent. I have tried adding it into the Child's `props.onChange(event, index)` but that didn't work. And i've fiddled as much as I can but am stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Parent:

```
 <Inputs hasInputs={hasInputs} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} thoughtProp={this.state.thought} onChange={event => { this.handleChange(event, index) }} />
```

Child:

```
export const Inputs = (props) => {
    return (
        <form className="flex-item-main form" onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <div>
                    <h4>
                      <p className='inputsHeader'>Thoughts:</p>  
                    </h4>
                </div>
            <ol>
              {props.thoughtProp.map((input, index) => (
                <Input type='text' key={index} value={input} onChange={props.onChange} className='textInputs' />
              ))}
              { props.hasInputs ? (
                <input className='submitThoughts' type='submit' value='Submit Thought!' />
              ) : (
                null
              )}
            </ol>
          </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the index as well

In the parent

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

In the child

```
onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e, index)}
```

Comment: I get the error ```props.onChange is not a function```

Comment: Is your parent a class component and your child a functional component?

Comment: Yes exactly, parent Class component and child functional

Comment: well, that's weird, I created this codesandbox with a working example using the same I put in the answer https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dust-cxk29?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you're right, must be something else. shoot. hmm. ok. back to the drawing board.

Comment: Figured it out. I never bound ``` (this)``` to  ```this.handleChange``` . massive eye roll.